# How to inherit vue.js json(filename)

Tags: vue.js

Json format received from server

```
{ 
  "file_name": "20191107-100439_2.jpg"
}
```

I want to load an image by inheriting the file name.

```
<img src ="../{{msg.file_name}}">
```

Is there a good way?

Comment: why would you receive a file name from server that has a relative path? Besides that, I guess `v-bind:src=` + Javascript string template literal.

Comment: This is to find the right name because multiple users upload images.

Comment: Then how can the client load the image with a relative path? Are you doing server side rendering?

Comment: Yes, it is.~~~~

Comment: Try this probably? https://www.codepile.net/pile/n3RBKO3B

Comment: There is no error, but the image cannot be loaded.

Comment: If you are using webpack, try `<img src="require(\`../${msg.file_name}\`)">`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
<img src="require(`../${msg.file_name}`)">
```

Helper. Ricky